Merging shapefile with data file with coordinates
I have a shapefile 'shp' with boundaries, and I have a data .csv file with coordinates and some values. I want to join the df to shp, so that each coordinate/observation would be in the correct zone/boundary. They don't have any fields in common.
What I've done, but I get an error:
shape_df <- st_join(shp, df, join = st_intersects)

(st_contains gives the same error)
Data types:
> class(shp)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

 > class(df)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

> st_crs(shp)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: OSGB36 / British National Grid 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",

>st_crs(df)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: OSGB36 / British National Grid 
  wkt:
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",
    BASEGEOGCRS["OSGB36",

Error:
Error in UseMethod("st_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_join' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"

What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this?

The issue here is that you are trying to use objects of the sp package with the sf package. Both class systems are usual representations of spatial vectors in R, but you should use now sf as sp has been superseded.
This error line is a consequence of using sp objects with sf functions.
Error in UseMethod("st_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_join' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"

Full explanation and solution starts here:
First we reproduce your input data (as you didn't provide any):
library(sp)
library(sf)

# Load example data as sp mocking your data
shp <- as(
  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE),
  "Spatial"
)

shp <- spTransform(shp, "EPSG:27700")
df <- spsample(shp, 100, type = "regular")

class(shp)
#> [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"

class(df)
#> [1] "SpatialPoints"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"

st_crs(shp)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid 
#>   wkt: ... <ommited>

st_crs(df)
#>   User input: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid 
#>   wkt: ... <ommited>

So far I just reproduced your input class, now trigger the same error you experienced.

# Reproduce your problem

shape_df <- st_join(shp, df, join = st_intersects)
#> Error in UseMethod("st_join"): no applicable method for 'st_join' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial')"

See? The solution is to convert sp to sf with st_as_sf():

# Convert objects to sf

shp_sf <- st_as_sf(shp)
df_sf <- st_as_sf(df)

class(shp_sf)
#> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"

class(df_sf)
#> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"

st_crs(shp_sf)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid 
#>   wkt: ... <ommited>

st_crs(df_sf)
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid 
#>   wkt: ... <ommited>

And finally try with your objects in sf format:

# Try now
shape_df_ok <- st_join(shp_sf, df_sf, join = st_intersects)
shape_df_ok
#> Simple feature collection with 120 features and 14 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -6818325 ymin: 2040366 xmax: -6133675 ymax: 3276116
#> Projected CRS: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
#> First 10 features:
#>     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID        NAME  FIPS FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74
#> 1  0.114     1.442  1825    1825        Ashe 37009  37009        5  1091     1
#> 2  0.061     1.231  1827    1827   Alleghany 37005  37005        3   487     0
#> 3  0.143     1.630  1828    1828       Surry 37171  37171       86  3188     5
#> 4  0.070     2.968  1831    1831   Currituck 37053  37053       27   508     1
#> 5  0.153     2.206  1832    1832 Northampton 37131  37131       66  1421     9
#> 6  0.097     1.670  1833    1833    Hertford 37091  37091       46  1452     7
#> 7  0.062     1.547  1834    1834      Camden 37029  37029       15   286     0
#> 8  0.091     1.284  1835    1835       Gates 37073  37073       37   420     0
#> 9  0.118     1.421  1836    1836      Warren 37185  37185       93   968     4
#> 10 0.124     1.428  1837    1837      Stokes 37169  37169       85  1612     1
#>    NWBIR74 BIR79 SID79 NWBIR79                       geometry
#> 1       10  1364     0      19 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6482310 29...
#> 2       10   542     3      12 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6449412 28...
#> 3      208  3616     6     260 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6434518 27...
#> 4      123   830     2     145 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6178830 21...
#> 5     1066  1606     3    1197 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6263566 23...
#> 6      954  1838     5    1237 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6236929 22...
#> 7      115   350     2     139 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6178830 21...
#> 8      254   594     2     371 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6209010 22...
#> 9      748  1190     2     844 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6321917 24...
#> 10     160  2038     5     176 MULTIPOLYGON (((-6412466 27...

Created on 2024-06-25 with reprex v2.1.0


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  C.UTF-8
#>  ctype    C.UTF-8
#>  tz       UTC
#>  date     2024-06-25
#>  pandoc   3.1.1 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  class         7.3-22  2023-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  classInt      0.4-10  2023-09-05 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  cli           3.6.3   2024-06-21 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  DBI           1.2.3   2024-06-02 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  digest        0.6.36  2024-06-23 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  e1071         1.7-14  2023-12-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  evaluate      0.24.0  2024-06-10 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  fastmap       1.2.0   2024-05-15 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  fs            1.6.4   2024-04-25 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  glue          1.7.0   2024-01-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.8.1 2024-04-04 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  KernSmooth    2.23-24 2024-05-17 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  knitr         1.47    2024-05-29 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  lattice       0.22-6  2024-03-20 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.4   2023-11-07 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  proxy         0.4-27  2022-06-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  purrr         1.0.2   2023-08-10 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.cache       0.16.0  2022-07-21 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.methodsS3   1.8.2   2022-06-13 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.oo          1.26.0  2024-01-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.utils       2.12.3  2023-11-18 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.12  2024-01-09 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  reprex        2.1.0   2024-01-11 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  rlang         1.1.4   2024-06-04 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  rmarkdown     2.27    2024-05-17 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  rstudioapi    0.16.0  2024-03-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  sf          * 1.0-16  2024-03-24 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  sp          * 2.1-4   2024-04-30 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  styler        1.10.3  2024-04-07 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  units         0.8-5   2023-11-28 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  vctrs         0.6.5   2023-12-01 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  withr         3.0.0   2024-01-16 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  xfun          0.45    2024-06-16 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#>  yaml          2.3.8   2023-12-11 [1] RSPM (R 4.4.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4
#>  [2] /opt/R/4.4.1/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

